# How to stop push pull in gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have master access in git lab and I want to stop push and pull to the repository for all the users who access the repository, I want to freeze the repository.

I don't want to remove anybody's access, just want to ban push-pull access.

How to do this in git lab?

Comment: You can archive the repository, restrict everyones rights who is lower than author/mantainer, or make a wildcard blocking pull push on every branch in repo.

Comment: Not clear what is for you 'ban pull' ?

Comment: @Orel: View only access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Project -> Protected Branches` and select a branch you want to restrict access too. You can use a regex also to select a bunch of branches. Select Allow Push Access to No One.

Anybody who has read access on the repository can clone/pull the repository too. You can selectively remove users' access from the repository from `members` screen so that they cannot even read the repository.